possible to directly run buildkit without docker buildx create? need to support dynamic autoscaled builder pool
We recently converted all our Jenkins docker builds to multi-arch, and it's generally working pretty well.  They're building on ARM-based instances, so the x86 builds are going through qemu, which takes a long time, and also has some glitches (for a couple Go projects, in particular).
I'm happy to spin up some dedicated x86 build resources.  The only tricky bit is that our build agents are autoscaled, so some of the recipes I've seen for configuring a "remote" builder that knows a particular architecture would require more code to find an active agent.
Our docker orchestration framework lets us expand any running service ip/port requirement into the environment of another service as a dependency, so I could probably create a dummy image that just wraps the docker buildx create step.  And it would need to hang out to determine if the remote builder has disappeared and been replaced.  But it occurred to me that it would be cleaner to just add buildkit to my cluster manifest directly and pass the remote builder in that way.
Is there a way to directly docker run a buildkit in the same way that docker buildx create would?
(Side note: if I can talk to buildkit through haproxy and it isn't going to assume that it gets the same backend every time it connects, that would greatly simplify things, as I could just point the remote at the reverse proxy and let the service routing rules track the dynamic backends.)

For Go in particular, the standard go build toolchain has pretty good cross-compilation support.  Can you use a native-architecture image to cross-build a binary, and then use an interpreted-architecture image only to produce the final image (and often that's just COPYing the built binary into some minimal base, without needing to RUN anything)?

@DavidMaze yup, that's how I worked around our Go-specific build issues; I do a native docker run -v$(pwd):/build -e GOARCH=$arch sh -c "apk add git make; go mod vendor && make", and the Dockerfile just copies the results of that.  Solved the qemu crash, but this still leaves my loooong node-gyp builds of node-rdkafka.

Turns out that this is actually pretty straightforward.
On my autoscaled intel build machines, I'm doing the equivalent of
docker run moby/buildkit:latest --privileged --addr tcp://0.0.0.0:8086

I do the same on the arm build machines, except on a different port:
docker run moby/buildkit:latest --privileged --addr tcp://0.0.0.0:8085

on my Jenkins JNLP agents, I pass in (arbitrarily named) env vars to define the local and remote platforms as either linux/amd64 or linux/arm64, and an env var to define the local and remote servers created above, as tcp://<addr>:<port>.
local_name="$(echo $BUILDKIT_LOCAL_PLATFORM|sed -E 's/(.+\/)?(.*)/\2/')-builder"
docker buildx create --use --name multi-builder --node "${local_name}"\
  --platform="${BUILDKIT_LOCAL_PLATFORM}"\
  --driver remote "${BUILDKIT_LOCAL_SERVER}"

remote_name="$(echo $BUILDKIT_REMOTE_PLATFORM|sed -E 's/(.+\/)?(.*)/\2/')-builder"
docker buildx create --append --name multi-builder --node "${remote_name}"\
  --platform="${BUILDKIT_REMOTE_PLATFORM}"\
  --driver remote "${BUILDKIT_REMOTE_SERVER}"

The local server is tcp://<local-ip-address>:8085 or tcp://<ip-address>:8086 depending on the architecture, and the remote server... well that depends.  If you have a single build machine for each architecture, its easy, just hardcode the name or ip in the same syntax.  I went for bonus points by putting them behind haproxy in an autoscaling group.  So my remote server address is the DNS name of my proxy.  In case anyone finds this and is looking to do something similar, it actually works surprisingly well to have the build servers behind a proxy!  My setup looks like this:
frontend buildkit-amd
    bind *:8086
    mode tcp
    default_backend buildkit-amd
    acl corp-ip src -f /bastion/haproxy/allow/corp.allow
    tcp-request connection reject if !corp-ip
    timeout client 60m
    timeout connect 60s

frontend buildkit-arm
    bind *:8085
    mode tcp
    default_backend buildkit-arm
    acl corp-ip src -f /bastion/haproxy/allow/corp.allow
    tcp-request connection reject if !corp-ip
    timeout client 60m
    timeout connect 60s

with the backend server lists generated dynamically (I use etcd/confd):
backend buildkit-arm
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    timeout server 60m


    server buildkit-arm-2ef8437b8c226e0cee4b13d1e216906fe4eda78c7147c33b79d131dbaa0f2f64 10.2.1.60:8085
    server buildkit-arm-868212ff42b1dc35be162182c219f15a9df161424b5517964402750ff730407e 10.2.3.80:8085

backend buildkit-amd
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    timeout server 60m


    server buildkit-amd-21de68bf69b323ee5a7c4c388d878d32249f89af2abca16053b0331dc11296ce 10.2.5.13:8086
    server buildkit-amd-25b06ab35f2f34b333d8f8214c11d6aecb84c3fcfca19d63c0746cafa60f5416 10.2.1.239:8086

Note that I failed to get this working with haproxy's h2 mode, but tcp mode seems to work fine.  Note the increased timeouts necessary for the long-lived connection.  (Our setup is protected by an IP whitelist for our dev VPN; if you're more security minded, you'll want certs and whatnot.)
When I log into a build worker and docker exec a shell inside my JNLP agent, I can check my setup like this:
# docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE           DRIVER/ENDPOINT               STATUS    BUILDKIT   PLATFORMS
multi-builder*      remote
 \_ arm64-builder    \_ tcp://10.2.3.80:8085      running   v0.16.0    linux/arm64*, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
 \_ amd64-builder    \_ tcp://devproxy.mycorp.com:8086   running   v0.16.0    linux/amd64*, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
default             docker
 \_ default          \_ default                   running   v0.16.0    linux/arm64

If everything is working, you'll see the "running" status on all your build workers.  (One completely surprising thing for me is that docker buildx ls shows different results if I run it at the host level vs. inside a container that mounts /var/run/docker.sock!  Most docker stuff is the same, but buildkit pays attention to docker contexts, which is not an area I've explored much.)
This was a pretty niche Q (&A) but I hope it helps someone out there!
